# Calculating Degrees Minutes Seconds (DMS) to nearest tenth of second in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, labeling

Is there a simple way to calculate coordinates in DMS to the nearest tenth second? I need DD MM SS.s (not DD MM SS.sss). By default, Pro calculates out to 8 decimal places. I just need it rounded to the 1st decimal place.